# Switching background image smoothly - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am facing problem concerning switching background in Angular 10. I managed to implement switching background image but I would like it to be smooth.
At this moment it looks kind of like the slideshow - one image disappears and the other one appears.

My piece of code looks like this:
In typescript component I hold array of variables with urls to image.

```
backgroundImages = ['url(/assets/img/background.jpg)', 'url(/assets/img/background2.jpg)']
```

And in constructor I call refresh method which basically changes the value of variable holding reference to current background

```
refreshBackground(backgroundNumber: number) {
    this.background = this.backgroundImages[backgroundNumber]
    if (backgroundNumber == this.backgroundImages.length - 1)
      backgroundNumber = 0
    else
      backgroundNumber++
    setTimeout(() => this.refreshBackground(backgroundNumber), 10000)
  }
```

In html this variable is set to style.background

```
<div class="container background" [style.background]="background">
```

I would appreciate any help and tips and if more details are needed, ask freely.

Michael